# How can I add a jQuery autocomplete handler to a form created dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, autocomplete, dialog

This is the first time I'm asking a question on here. I have a decent amount of experience with PHP, but I'm relatively new to jQuery.

I have a table that I generate via PHP that contains data for Yoga classes. When a user clicks on one of the table rows, the data for that row is sent to an Ajax call to a PHP routine that produces a dialog box. In that dialog box, I want the "teacher" field to have an autocomplete attached to it, so that if the user wants to change the teacher they can start typing and the system will find the current teachers and return close matches.

The dialog box works, but the autocomplete does not. I believe the issue is that the form in the dialog box is generated dynamically, so it doesn't exist at load so the bind fails. I tried changing the jQuery to use the .on("keyup") handler, but that doesn't seem to work either.

How can I get this to work?

jQuery code:

```
$(function () {            

            $(document).on("click", "#scheduleTable tbody tr", function(e) {
                var pos = { my: "center center", at: "center top+150", of: window };
                var rowid = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
                var rowdata = rowid.substring(3);
                var request = $.ajax({
                     url: "./log_getTemplateClassData.php",
                     method: "POST",
                     data: { rowdata:rowdata }
                });
                request.done(function(response){
                    $("#edit_template_results").append(response);
                    $("#edit_template_dialog").dialog("open");
                });
                request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                     alert(textStatus+': '+errorThrown);
                });
                request.always(function(){
                    // do nothing
                });

            });

            $(document).on("keyup", "#teacher", function(){
                $("#teacher").autocomplete({
                    source: "./log_getAllTeachers.php"
                });    
            });

     });    

    $(document).ready(function() {

      var pos = { my: "center center", at: "center top+150", of: window };

         $(function() {
              $("#edit_template_dialog").dialog({
                  position: pos,
                  width: "auto",
                  autoOpen: false,
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                      "Save ": function() {
                          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                          $("#saveForm").val("save");
                          location.reload();
                      },
                      "Cancel ": function(){
                          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                          $("#saveForm").val("cancel");
                          location.reload();
                      }
                  }
                });
            });

        $("#edit_template_dialog").on("dialogclose", function(e){
            location.reload();
        })

    });
```

The PHP-generated dialog box:

```
<div id="edit_template_dialog" title="Edit Template Class" class="ui-helper-hidden" >
        <form id="edit_template_dialog_form">
            <table id="edit_template_results" class="data" align="center">
        <tr class="odd">
                <th>
                    <label for="weekDay">Weekday</label>
                </th>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <select name="weekDay id="weekDay">
                        <option selected="selected" value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
                        <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                        <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>                        
                        <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                        <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                        <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
                        <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <th>
                    Class Start Time
                </th>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <select name="classHour" id="classHour"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option selected="selected" value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option></select><select name="classMinute" id="classMinute"><option selected="selected" value="00">00</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="45">45</option></select><select name="classAMPM" id="classAMPM"><option value="AM">AM</option><option selected="selected" value="PM">PM</option></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <th>
                    Class Name
                </th>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input class="input3" name="className" type="text" id="className" size="50" value="Yoga Nidra" maxlength="125">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <th>
                    Teacher
                </th>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input class="input3" name="teacher" type="text" id="teacher" size="50" value="Kathi Szabo" maxlength="125">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <th>
                    Meeting ID
                </th>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input class="input3" name="meetingID" type="text" id="meetingID" size="50" value="942893906123" maxlength="15">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <th>
                    <label for="nationalYN">National Schedule?</label>
                </th>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="nationalYN" id="nationalYN" >
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
        </form>
    </div>
```

The PHP to do the autocomplete:

```
<?php

    require_once('conn.php');

    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    $getAllTeachers_query = "SELECT DISTINCT(tplTeacher) FROM tblTemplateClasses WHERE tplTeacher LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY tplTeacher ASC";

    $getAllTeachers_result = $conn->query($getAllTeachers_query);

    if ($getAllTeachers_result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while ($getAllTeachers_row = $getAllTeachers_result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $data['id']    = $getAllTeachers_row['id'];
            $data['value'] = $getAllTeachers_row['tplTeacher'];
            array_push($teacherList, $data);
        }        
    }

    echo json_encode($teacherList);


?>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, @Dharman. I'll fix that once I get the autocomplete to actually work.

Comment: I believe you should move the the initialisation of the jQuery Autocomplete to the end of the `done`-section of your ajax-request.  Now you will re-initiatie your autocomplete every time you press a key, which might interfere with the autocoomplete.

Comment: Thanks, @Zombaya. I just tried that and it had no effect.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), I'm guessing your sources are not in a proper format.  I believe the response should be `[{label:'Teacher 1',value:'id1'},...]`.   Other than that, I would firstly use a static javascript-array and only then try to source it by ajax, just to eliminate one extra source of problems.

Comment: Thanks, @Zombaya. I tried that at first and it wasn't working either. I tried changing it back and it's still not working. I really think the issue is it not binding to the dynamic form.

Comment: Oops, scratch that, @Zombaya. When I move it to the .done and make it static, it does work. Cool! now I'm making progress again!

Comment: Great! Could you post your final solution (preferably with the fixed SQL-injection) as an answer as to provide help for future visitors to this question?

Comment: I could, @Zombaya, but the current version looks way different than this version and I completely abandoned the Ajax / PHP for the autocomplete in favor of inserting the list into my jQuery via PHP, so I'm not sure it's really the best example.